# What is MS SQL table's sys.allocation_units alternative table in Oracle?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I have a query in MS SQL which I need to convert in Oracle for obtaining the same results as in MS SQL.

But I am unable to find the corresponding system tables in Oracle Database which would give me the required columns/results.

Please help me to build the equivalent oracle for the following MS SQL query.

The MS SQL query is:-

```
SELECT
   TOP 10 B.TableName AS TableName,
   A.used_mb AS used_mb,
   A.allocated_mb AS allocated_mb,
   REPLACE(A.Ratio_used_mb, '%', '') AS Ratio_used_mb,
   REPLACE(A.Ratio_allocated_mb, '%', '') AS Ratio_allocated_mb,
   B.RowCounts AS RowCounts,
   B.TotalPages AS TotalPages,
   B.UsedPages AS UsedPages,
   B.DataPages AS DataPages,
   DATEPART(WEEK, GETUTCDATE()) AS Weekvalue 
FROM
   (
      SELECT
         tab.name AS TableName,
         CAST(SUM(spc.used_pages * 8) / 1024.00 AS NUMERIC(36, 2)) AS used_mb,
         CAST(SUM(spc.total_pages * 8) / 1024.00 AS NUMERIC(36, 2)) AS allocated_mb,
         FORMAT((CAST(SUM(spc.used_pages * 8) / 1024.00 AS NUMERIC(36, 2))) / ( 
         SELECT
            CAST(SUM(spc.used_pages * 8) / 1024.00 AS NUMERIC(36, 2)) AS used_mb 
         FROM
            sys.tables tab 
            JOIN
               sys.indexes ind 
               ON tab.object_id = ind.object_id 
            JOIN
               sys.partitions part 
               ON ind.object_id = part.object_id 
               AND ind.index_id = part.index_id 
            JOIN
               sys.allocation_units spc 
               ON part.partition_id = spc.container_id), 'P') AS Ratio_used_mb,
               FORMAT((CAST(SUM(spc.total_pages * 8) / 1024.00 AS NUMERIC(36, 2))) / ( 
               SELECT
                  CAST(SUM(spc.total_pages * 8) / 1024.00 AS NUMERIC(36, 2)) AS allocated_mb 
               FROM
                  sys.tables tab 
                  JOIN
                     sys.indexes ind 
                     ON tab.object_id = ind.object_id 
                  JOIN
                     sys.partitions part 
                     ON ind.object_id = part.object_id 
                     AND ind.index_id = part.index_id 
                  JOIN
                     sys.allocation_units spc 
                     ON part.partition_id = spc.container_id), 'P') AS Ratio_allocated_mb 
               FROM
                  sys.tables tab 
                  JOIN
                     sys.indexes ind 
                     ON tab.object_id = ind.object_id 
                  JOIN
                     sys.partitions part 
                     ON ind.object_id = part.object_id 
                     AND ind.index_id = part.index_id 
                  JOIN
                     sys.allocation_units spc 
                     ON part.partition_id = spc.container_id 
               GROUP BY
                  tab.name
   )
   A 
   FULL JOIN
      (
         SELECT
            t.name AS TableName,
            SUM(p.ROWS) AS RowCounts,
            SUM(a.total_pages) AS TotalPages,
            SUM(a.used_pages) AS UsedPages,
            SUM(a.data_pages) AS DataPages 
         FROM
            sys.tables t 
            INNER JOIN
               sys.indexes i 
               ON t.object_id = i.object_id 
            INNER JOIN
               sys.partitions p 
               ON i.object_id = p.object_id 
               AND i.index_id = p.index_id 
            INNER JOIN
               sys.allocation_units a 
               ON p.partition_id = a.container_id 
         WHERE
            t.name NOT LIKE 'dt%' 
            AND i.object_id > 255 
            AND i.index_id <= 1 
         GROUP BY
            t.name,
            i.object_id,
            i.index_id,
            i.name
      )
      B 
      ON B.TableName = A.TableName 
ORDER BY
   B.UsedPages DESC
```

Comment: Please, describe what the information you need, not just a query

Comment: I need the details of each table present in Oracle Database. The table name , its consumed memory in MB, allocated memory in MB, ratio of used memory in MB, ration of allocated memory in MB, total number of rows in the table, total number of pages , total number used pages and total number of data pages.

Comment: Tables do not consume memory, and they are not allocated in memory.  They are allocated storage and consume storage.  Memory and storage are two distinctly different things.  You may say it's just semantics, but in this business we need to be precise - just like in medicine.  I don't think you'd want your doctor to talk about removing a kidney when he really means to remove your infected appendix, then say "it's just semantics".

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/cncpt/introduction-to-oracle-database.html#GUID-6DA14086-C6A4-422E-8131-BE00B32CD01B

Answer (score 1):

There probably isn't a one-for-one same table.  The architecture of the two products is fundamentally different, as is the method of space (storage) allocation. Take a look at DBA_TABLES, DBA_SEGMENTS, DBA_EXTENTS.  They are all documented in the Database Reference. That manual for Oracle 18 is located [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/refrn/index.html).